# write a function and mapping in r

Tags: r, function, dictionary

I have a dataframe1 telling the meaning of each value like this

value    meaning
1         red
2         blue
3         green
...       ...

and I have another large dataframe2 like this
id   color    weight   width
1     1         98        32
...  ...        ...      ...

I tried to write a function and then map to my dataframe2 and change my color column.
My code is

```
color<-function(x){
  for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe1)){
    if(x == dataframe1$value[i]){
      x = dataframe1$meaning[i]
  }
}
map(dataframe2$color ,color)
```

And I got Nulls
Anyone can help with me? I know I can do for loops to change the value but the dataset is so big and it takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you would like to do, i.e. attach the descriptions from dataframe 1 to dataframe 2 based on the colour-code?

This is a vectorised solution avoiding a loop.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data_df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~colour, ~weight, ~width,
  1, 1, 20, 30,
  2, 2, 30, 20
)

colour_df <- tribble(
  ~value, ~meaning,
  1, "red",
  2, "blue"
)

data_df |> 
  left_join(colour_df, by = c("colour" = "value"))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>      id colour weight width meaning
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1     1      1     20    30 red    
#> 2     2      2     30    20 blue
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>